# Multiple switching power supplies sharing the same(v-) reference

Tags: power-supply

I need multiple 5v switching power supplies to power around 12,000 WS2812 digital Leds. I also need a MCU, which will be powered by a 12v supply through a DC bulk converter.

[image]

The goal is to have every led and the MCU have the same reference ground(v-) so the MCU can properly send digital signal to the LEDs. What is the proper way to do it? Can I simply connect the V- of each power supply together?

[image]

Comment: You *should* be able to do this. How far apart will the power supplies be?

Comment: They are placed next to each other.

Comment: In that case, you have have trouble with your ground potential "drifting" if you are trying to power all of them in a long string. As a side note, it may be problematic to control that many LEDs with a single data line (it may take too much time to scan through them all).

Comment: [DATA SHEET](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf) says pulse shaping per unit and 5m max distance. At about 20 mA/LED and 5A per 5V supply that's about 250 LED's per supply. | At about 1.3 uS/bit and 24 bits/LED =~ 32 uS/LED, 12000 in series !!!! would take about 400 mS to clock - should Murphy not intervene. He will. | 12000 LEDS/250-per-supply ~= 50 supplies !!! [Meanwell et al make != 40A plus 5V supplies] | Multiple parallel sets of serial feeds and intelligent ground and 5V gridding should allow voltage drops to be within limits. |More discussion if wanted ...